# Mocking a config file using jest and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, next.js, jestjs

I have looked around and there are similar questions but none which cover this particular case.

In my project, I have a useConfig() function which uses an api call to return an object containing several properties.

In the component I am trying to test, there is a conditional based on the return of useConfig() to determine what should be rendered, i.e. siteConfig.condition_is_met

I have been trying to use jest.mock() functions to provide this value to my tests, but I have been unsuccessful.  I have spent a lot of time with the documentation but there is some key thing I'm missing.

Here is a minimal version of my first test:

```
 it('renders maintenance notice when maintenance mode is true', async () => {
    const { getByText } = act(() => {
      render(<MyComponent>{'Children Content'}</MyComponent>)
    })

   
      const maintenanceNoticeLabel = getByText('Website Wartung')
      const maintenanceNoticeHeading = getByText(/Wir sind gerade dabei/i)
      const maintenanceNoticeBody = getByText(/Wir arbeiten derzeit daran/i)
      expect(maintenanceNoticeLabel).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(maintenanceNoticeHeading).toBeInTheDocument()
      expect(maintenanceNoticeBody).toBeInTheDocument()
    
  })
```

The problem is that this doesn't actually check if maintenenceMode is set to true or not, and I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Any help at all is appreciated.

I tried to mock the function to access a return, i.e.

```
jest.mock('../../../common/data/useSiteConfig', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    siteConfig: {
      maintenance_mode: 'true',
      agency_slug: 'example-agency'
    }
  })
}))
```

and tried to access the value that way but without success.

Comment: Show the debugging details. What's the error? What result does the `useConfig()` return?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  there's not specifically an error, it's more about wanting to know how to mock a conditional which comes from a config object.  For example, the component looks something like:

`{siteConfig.maintenence_mode ? <div>hello</div> : <p>oh dear</p>}`

where siteConfig comes from my useConfig function.  I've tried several approaches but i haven't successfully been able to mock this in my test